# How many hash functions must Bob compute to find a solution?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, preimage-resistance, 2nd-preimage-resistance

> Alice  proposes  the  following  puzzle  to  be  completed.
>   Let m be  the  body  of  the  email message,
>   let a be  the  recipient’s  email  address,
>   let H(  )be  the  hash  function  SHA3-256, and
>   let x be  an  arbitrary  256-bit  value.
>   The  sender  must  send  the  value x such  that  the output of H(m|a|x) is smaller than the following value: $2^{215}$
>
> How many hash functions must Bob compute to find a solution?

Comment: What would you expect?

Comment: Hints: the question and the rules governing the body of emails allow $m$ to be the value of $x$ in hexadecimal, or even $x$ itself with some restrictions on $x$ that still leave the task feasible. Cryptographers assimilate bistrings to integers (in big-endian order) without even noticing it, e.g. in expressions like _"the output of H(..) is smaller than.."_, except in carefully written standards and some extra-picky textbooks. The base-two logarithm of the answer is likely less than [The Answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

Answer (score 1):

See the hash as a $256$-bit number. This number is smaller than $2^{215}$ iff the upper $40$ bits are all $0$.

Suppose that a bit of the output of the hash has an equal chance to be $0$ or $1$....

Comment: ..is smaller than $2^{215}$ (give or take some) iff..